# How to change default behaviour of hg log to only show ancestors?

Tags: mercurial, hg-log

Is it possible to change the default behaviour of `hg log` to show only the current ancestors?

Ie this:

```
hg log --rev "reverse(ancestors(.))"
```

The thing is, I *always* want `hg log` to do that.

I know that I could do something like this in my `.bashrc` but I was wondering if there was a mercurial way to do this.

```
hg () {

    if [[ $2 -eq "log" ]]
    then
        # TODO: Append other arguments to this...
        hg log --rev "reverse(ancestors(.))" 
    else
        # Run the command
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias function of `hg` is the right tool for this. While you can create aliases that modify the default behavior of built-in commands, `hg config` (section `"alias"`) has the following to say:

```
Note:
   It is possible to create aliases with the same names as existing
   commands, which will then override the original definitions. This is
   almost always a bad idea!
```

The recommended practice is to create an alias `alog` and simply train your fingers to type `hg alog` instead of `hg log`. Placing this in `~/.hgrc` (or equivalent) will do it:

```
[alias]
alog = log --rev "reverse(ancestors(.))"
```

Why is this a better solution? Not only does an alias for `log` block you from accessing the original behavior (requiring *another* alias that claws back the original meaning); more importantly, once you come to expect the non-standard behavior, sooner or later you'll get bit when you type `hg log` in an another account or context that's not controlled by your `.hgrc`. (Typing `hg alog` in the same circumstances will only incur an "unknown command" error).

Answer (score 4):

While you can accomplish that with an alias (see below), the cleanest approach here is an extension:

```
from mercurial import extensions, commands

testedwith = "3.5"

default_log_rev = "reverse(ancestors(.))"

def override_log(original_cmd, ui, repo, *pats, **opts):
  have_rev = False
  for opt in ["rev", "branch"]:
    if opts.has_key(opt) and opts[opt]:
      have_rev = True
  if not have_rev:
    opts["rev"] = [default_log_rev]
  return original_cmd(ui, repo, *pats, **opts)

def uisetup(ui):
  extensions.wrapcommand(commands.table, "log", override_log)
```

This will only use your new default if neither the `--rev` nor the `--branch` options (or their abbreviations `-r` and `-b`) of `log` are set, thus preserving the original behavior if one of them is provided.

You can install such an extension in the usual way, i.e. by adding something like the following to your `~/.hgrc` (assuming that the above code is in `/path/to/logdefault.py`):

```
[extensions]
logdefault = /path/to/logdefault.py
```

If an extension is to heavyweight for you, you can also create an alias in your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
log = log --rev 'reverse(ancestors(.))'
rawlog = !$HG --config alias.log=log log "$@"
```

The second alias (`rawlog`) exists so that you can still access the original `log` functionality.

Comment: What is "cleaner" about an extension? It seems like terrible overkill for something that can be done with a simple option, and hence can easily be encapsulated in an alias.

Comment: It's cleaner in that it doesn't break the normal functioning of `hg log -r <rev>`. The extension can check if there's already a revision argument and not supply a default in this case; an alias cannot.

Comment: Right, then it's kinda necessary when you override the original name... Thanks.